# jQuery Mobile Form Not Validating

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, contact-form

Okay, at first I was having trouble with the form not making to my email address. I got that fixed with ajax, now I can't seem to get my validation working. Here is my code for the form, and the one css style being called for the validation: http://jsfiddle.net/gbaH7/

Here is what I'm trying to emulate: http://jsfiddle.net/na7bv/light/

Comment: The fiddle for your code is blank.

Comment: What fields are you trying to validate? The email validation is working in your example if you change the jQuery version to 1.6.4 (you had it on 1.2.6).

Comment: Its not being checked when I hit submit. That is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "return false;" statement in your submit click event handler is blocking the validation.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: But now it still sends messages on every submit. Even when it isn't correctly filled out.